# Is it possible in Powershell to enter a value to a program via script?

Tags: powershell

I'm quite new to powershell. I would like to create a powershell script that starts automatically and writes sth into the window. It should also work with task scheduler. It seems possible to start a program by using `Start-Process`. For example I start a program and would like to enter a text. How can I do it while it being executable using the task scheduler when a user is not logged in?

I found wshell.SendKeys but it only works when the user is logged in. Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this at the time of execution, like if you did it from the command line it would be something like `MyApp.exe sth`, or is there a user interface that comes up after the program is launched where the 'sth' needs to be input? `Start-Process` has an `-ArgumentList` parameter you could provide the arguments to if it happens at time of execution.

Comment: yes, it's like app.exe and it opens a window like a cmd prompt. I have to enter value for it to execute, like a password. I'm afraid it has to start and then I have to enter. Like it's running a script and after 3 sec I'm asked to enter the value

Answer (score 0):

In a file test.ps1 save this.

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
Start-Process Notepad
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
$wshell.AppActivate('Notepad')
$wshell.SendKeys('Hello World')
```

In the task scheduler configure to your needs.

```
Program: "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" 
Arguments: -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File test.ps1
```

Paths must be adjusted, try with absolute paths first. Be aware that the scheduled task must be somehow user interactive.